# Server doesn't want to connect to the wired network

Tags: 12.04, networking, server

I just got home and moved my server from my apartment to my house, and for some reason my Ubuntu server doesn't want to obtain an IP from our router. It is setup for a dynamic IP, and it was working perfectly fine before I moved it. I'm currently getting a "Waiting for network configuration..." during boot before it times out.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I've also tried setting a static IP but no other computer on my network can hit it. As I've said, I changed nothing to the network config, the only thing that changed was the network setup and both places I'm really lost and would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Must be a problem of a lower layer. Check link status using `ethtool eth0`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have ethtool installed, and without ethernet, I ironically can't install it

Answer (score 0):

Some DHCP servers can be configured only to grant leases to machines with registered MAC addresses. Check your router configuration for this kind of restriction and, if necessary, register your server's MAC address.